# How to minimize camera module?

Tags: hardware, camera

I am developing a project with camera module. The camera will locate into glasses frames. It is similar as the following:

https://learn.adafruit.com/prescription-snapchat-spectacles/overview?view=all

Have any ways can minimize camera module? The board of camera module is too large.
[image]

Comment: Given what can be inferred about your knowledge of electronics, please don't even try this. The board was produced that size for a reason. There is no way to make it significantly smaller. What you can't see in the photo is all of the necessary components on the back of the board.

Answer (score 1):

While you have no chance whatsoever of cutting bits off the official Pi camera module without destroying it, alternatives are available. Adafruit, for example, stock [this miniature CSI camera](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1937) designed for use with the Pi which is substantially smaller.

[image: Adafruit Raspberry Pi Spy Camera]

I've never used one but they describe the module as being 'capable of 2592 x 1944 pixel static images, and also supports 1080p30, 720p60 and 640x480p60/90 video'. I think it's likely that similar modules are available on eBay if you're prepared to do some research.